# Using Java on visual studio

Tags: java, visual-studio

Is it possible to use java on visual studio?
If the answer is no,then what IDEs that support java and make windows native applications,as well?

Comment: Please at least try to search Google before posting these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many IDE's that support Java which Google can show you. Common ones used include Eclipse, NetBeans, and Intellij Idea. There may be plug-ins to allow Visual Studio to help you do Java coding, but I can't imagine that this would work better than the IDE's that were initially created for Java coding.

As to making "windows native applications". If you mean .exe's, then no, this is not an IDE type of issue. With Java you create JAR files which can run on Windows and other platforms as well. Yes .exe's can be made using various tools, including Jet, but in general you're usually better off not going this route and instead creating JAR files.